# Show images from web in winRT application

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Binding data to the `GridView`, each item in colliection have property with URL to image on external server.

When just binding it to Image component, get lags while images loading.

So what is thebest way to show many images from web in winRT (c#) application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class which asynchronously downloads the images and sets a property of your data model (which implemenents `INotifyPropertyChanged`). This way you will not experience any lag and the image will be shown when it's downloaded.

Comment: And better to bind images as bitmap for `Image`, or save them and bind using path?

Comment: I think this depends what kind of images you are downloading. If they will not change in a certain time, it would be better to cache them. If they change everytime you switch to this page, you maybe don't want to cache them.